# call cms/phtml from controller

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have designed homepage from cms by calling phtml file there. I am able to see that cms page in default index.php file.

Then, i have created website. I want to display this cms page in home page of my new website(index contorller and index action).

I have tried to display directly phtml file from controller but couldn't succeeded.
I tried [this](http://blog.emiprotechnologies.com/call-phtml-file-from-controller-in-magento/),but it wasn't showing any result.

i want to display phtml file from controller, either directly or by calling cms page. 
But not able to do it.

**UPDATE:**
I was able to load phtml file. But it doesn't showing result from only this file(from original file images are not loading but i am looking into it).
It's showing default layout as well.I want to remove default layout and only want to show the file i loaded from code.

loading content from two different files(i guess), I want to remove unwanted content from to and left.

[image]
How this can be done ?

Comment: $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('FOLDER_NAME/FILE_NAME.phtml')->toHtml();

Comment: after that you have setBody($html) to view your output

Comment: i used this.   $this->getResponse->setBody ($this->getLayout()->createBlock(‘core/template’)->setTemplate(‘page/homepage.phtml’)->toHtml());  i created homepage.phtml into theme/default/template/page/homepage.phtml. i only to specify this much of path, right?

Comment: i wrote echo line and then this line. but it just displays what i wrote in echo, not displaying part of phtml file.

Comment: try to assign with some variable means take first variable which will call your phtml file then and assign this variable to setbody

Comment: still the same result

Comment: i did this         $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(‘core/template’)->setTemplate(‘page/homepage.phtml’)->toHtml();
        
         $this->getResponse->setBody($html);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37228/discussion-between-bsthakrar-and-keyur-shah)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello you will call block into cms page content like below

{{block type='core/template' template='hello.phtml'}} or

Add below code into your controller

```
$this->loadLayout();    
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','helloworld_index',array('template' => 'helloworld/index.phtml'));
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
$this->renderLayout();
```

Comment: i know i can call phtml from cms. i want to call cms from controller or directly phtml from controller. i know a way but it's not working.

Comment: nt getting desired result. see updated question i added screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It is always loading default because default handle in layout is not overriden. You have to create a new layout file. In your handle module_controller_action set the complete page layout. After that load this layout . Go through this would give you a brief idea http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts

Then create a layout.xml do search for this. Thats all that is required

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    $this->loadLayout();   
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session'); //messages (optional)
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Title')); //your page title (optional)
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('foldername/filename.phtml')->toHtml(); //set layout file
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    $this->renderLayout();
```